# After close or save, go to a list view other than AllItems

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, sharepoint-foundation, list-view

After clicking Save or Close on any from (NewForm or DispForm), is there a way to go back to the list page to a certain view other than AllItems?  So when I click "save" to a NewForm or DispForm or "close" it goes directly to a list view that I created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you provide a link to the new form or display form, include a query string parameter called `Source` that specifies the URL of the page to which you want the user to navigate upon closing the form.

For example:

```
https://mysharepointsite.server/site/web/lists/MyList/Forms/NewForm.aspx?Id=1&Source=https://mysharepoint.site.server/site/web/lists/MyList/MyFavoriteView.aspx
```

Comment: Thanks.  That worked perfectly.  It's basically kind of the same thing I did for hyperlinks:  the Source querystring